# How do I recover data from a Linux KVM virtual machine?

Tags: kvm, data-recovery

I am currently experiencing the following problem: after an untimely power outage, my Linux KVM virtual machine no longer boots up. It shows no signs of life at all. But there are many important files and information that I need.

Could you please advise me on how to solve the problem? Maybe someone has faced this problem. Or if the machine cannot be started, how can I get back the files that are very important to me?

Answer (score 0):

The 'libguestfs' utilities will allow you to test, repair, copt files to/from all the common kvm image formats.